# nginx отдаёт png и gif с разными скоростями

Tags: nginx

Nginx отдаёт статику прямо из директории.
Для тестирования взял два файла: png (3913 байт) и gif (3990 байт).
Размеры можно считать идентичными. Лежат рядом.

Браузером загружаю каждый. Смотрю время раздумья сервера:

png — 54ms

gif — 102ms

нигде в настройках ни по mime, ни по расширению они врозь не указываются.

значения средневзвешенные, после проведения около 20 тестов.

Понимаю, что инфы дал мало, но может у кого-нибудь будут догадки?

Comment: может в это время включено время декодирования изображения?

Comment: Кем?
Я считал время, которое прошло с момента отправки запроса до момента начала загрузки файла

Comment: Есть такое подозрение, что в Вашей сети MTU такое, что одним пакетом передается 1305-1330 байт или 3914-3989. (Можно и другие размеры подобрать, но 1305-1330 выглядит подходяще). В таком случае для передачи этих двух картинок нужно разное кол-во пакетов. А здесь вступает в работу обычный Naggle алгоритм. И один пакет задерживается.

Вы же тестите не на одной картинке, а на десятках? тогда 200 мс, которые даст naggle алгоритм как раз и даст эти 50 мс разницы.

Comment: @KoVadim, гугл утверждает что Nagle пишется с одной g

Comment: Для чистоты эксперимента возьмите один и тот же файл, и назовите его копии по-разному: `.gif` и `.png` — чтобы размер был идентичен. И для объективности надо хотя бы по 1000 запросов на каждый файл, вперемешку.

А конфиги MIME у вас стандартные, которые шли с nginx'ом?

Comment: MIME из коробки с nginx
хотел попробовать назвать по разному один файл, пока руки не дошли.
Заодно можно одному и тому же файлу разные MIME прописать

Answer (score 2):

А вы лучше попробуйте снять тесты с помощью ab. А то браузер тот еще тестировщик.